# How to call a recursive linked list traversal function in C++

Tags: c++, list, recursion, linked-list, traversal

I have this function:

```
    void TraverseRecursive ( Node * head, void (*visit) (Node *) )
    {
      if ( head != nullptr )
      {
        visit( head ) ;
        TraverseRecursive( head->next, visit ) ;
      }
    }
```

And I'm trying to call it in main.cpp with

```
TraverseRecursive ( head, TraverseRecursive ) ;
```

Which gives me the error "argument of type "void (*)(Node *head, void (*visit)(Node *))" is incompatible with parameter of type "void (*)(Node *)" "

So how do I correctly call it? I am just learning linked lists and obviously don't understand what

```
 void (*visit) (Node *)
```

means at all.

Comment: If you're just learning about recursion then by all means recurse away, but as @ikegami points out, traversing a list is an inherently non-recursive activity. You pay a run-time price for using recursion, so avoid it when possible unless it truly simplifies your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void (*visit) (Node *)
```

means "pointer to a function taking one argument of type Node* and returning void". But *TraverseRecurive* takes two argumenst and is therefore of different type.
You need to define a function like

```
void doSomething(Node* n)
{
}
```

and pass it to *TraverseRecursive*

Answer (score 1):

The second argument should be a function to call back for every node in the list. It only takes a single parameter (the node to "visit").

```
void visitor(Node *node)
{
  printf("%s\n", node->data);  // Or whatever
}

TraverseRecursive( head, visitor ) ;
```

---

Side note: What wasteful use of recursion. If you're lucky, the compiler will optimize it away. You should be using

```
void TraverseRecursive( Node * head, void (*visit) (Node *) )
{
  for (; head != nullptr; head = head->next)
  {
    visit( head ) ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks people! I got excited to use recursion because I was going to call a display function, then just switch the visit... and Traverse... lines to make it display backwards. I was trying to combine them into one horrible abomination, but thanks to ya'll now I can call Display from my traverse!